# Help on __gnu_cxx::hash_map

Tags: hashmap

Is there any document regarding "__gnu_cxx::hash_map"? 
I want to know how to use it.

Srinivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNU implementation of `hash_map` is basically the same as the one described in the [STL documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the document was not helpful. Is there any other better document?

Comment: In what way is it not helpful?

Comment: Though the document says what is what of functions and variables, it doesn't say how to use this, what are the things to be done for using this, what could be a key equality function, why eqstr is a structure and what overloaded operator() do..etc. kind of things. This document is looking similar to a header file. What I was looking for is a descriptive document...example. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/